# Android Studio 4 - No Devices Selected when choosing Open Android Emulator

Tags: android, flutter

I created and a new Pixel API 28 virtual device in the AVD Manager.  However in the main screen when I select the device from the list it launches the emulator but the device selector says there is "no device selected".  So when I run my project it says "No Connected Devices Found.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hp3M.png
```

Here is my flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.1.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E266, locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hp3M.png
```

Comment: Please see answer below about updating flutter plugin within android studio, and please upvote my answer if it works.  Hoping you have the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, android studio would say nothing connected.
Also the box in Android studio was always "Loading" instead of the simulator running, and trying to debug or run, would say no devices connected, while flutter doctor said that it was connected.  Also other editors were working, in my case visual studio code worked.

The fix:
Update android studio flutter plugin, possibly help by upgrading flutter with flutter upgrade.